# Calculated Column Extracting Date Only in Date and Time Column Type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Intent: To create a calculated column that shows the date ONLY from date and time column type.  I created a formula, but it is wrong and not sure where I am going wrong.  Can anyone help?  Note: I cannot change the column type to display 'Date' only.  I need to keep this column so creating a new column date column is not an option

`=TEXT(Start Date,"dddd")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
= TEXT([Start Date],"d/m/yyyy")
```

[image]

Output

```
2/9/2016
```

[image]