# How to hide time from Date field in SPD 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to display only date on my Business Related Web Part, but currently showing full Date Time how can i show only Date?

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about a List View WebPart, you can either:

- Change the display format of the datetime column of the list

[image]

- If you cannot change the display format, you can create an additional Calculated Column, with formula like `=TEXT([MyDateField],"d/m/yyyy")` (see [Calculated Column Extracting Date Only in Date and Time Column Type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192825/calculated-column-extracting-date-only-in-date-and-time-column-type))

Comment: This is my Business Related web part where can i set this settings?

Comment: When working with external lists, you should change the BCS model, to only display the datetime information.